# Application Error: Application Launch was not detected for application App

Tags: windows-store-apps

When I was validation my Windows Store App I got the following error:

> Application Error: Application Launch was not detected for application
>   App. This could be because your application failed to launch
>   correctly. Please consider re-running the test and avoid interacting
>   with the application while tests are running.

What does this mean? The app will not validate.

Comment: This happened once to me.  When it occurred, I also noticed another error - "Registration of the app failed. An internal error occurred with error 0x80073D05. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues. (0x80073cf6)".  The latter happens periodically, and the only remedy that I have found so far is rebooting the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was a bit weird and I couldn't find anything when I googled it but people who had almost the same problem as me, though rather than launching it was failing to sleep. This was just plain odd.

I tried to launch the app from Visual Studio 2012 just to prove to myself that it did start properly and for some crazy reason it didn't work. I usually test the game on my Local Machine rather than the Simulator but now, for some reason, it was set to the Simulator and I have been having problems getting it to start lately (the simulator).
I changed it back to the local machine and ran the tests again. This time it worked.

So, if you get this error it might be time to see if your simulator works and if not, have the Local Machine set as default to run with.